# How to create a array of buttons Object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I want to create 10 buttons using an array. How to create it? I am using

```
array  = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, button2] retain];
```

But It tells Missing Sentinel in Function Call. Where, I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *myButtons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, button2, nil];
```

Now your array has retain count 1 after allocation, so you don't have to retain it.

When you don't need the array, just release it

```
[myButtons release];
```

Comment: [array objectAtIndex:i.frame] = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 30);
Where I am wrong in this syntax. Here is a for loop.

Comment: @Tauquir: objectAtIndex requires integer. You should first retrieve object at index `i` into variable then assign its frame property to `CGRectMake(...)`;

Answer (score 1):

The `-initWithObjects:` method have to be `nil`-terminated:

```
array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, button2, nil];
//                                                       ^^^^^
```

Also, the `+alloc` method already returns an object with retain count of +1. There's no need to `-retain` it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the terminating nil for the array.

`array  = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, button2,nil] retain];`

But thats possibly leaky as you get a double retain. Better might be.

`array  = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1, button2,nil] retain];`

Comment: Can I shuffle the order of these objects in the array?

Comment: @KennyTM: Can you tell me how to shuffle these in the Array? Can You Provide me the Solution?

Comment: @Tacquir: Why don't you [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objective-c+shuffle)?

Comment: I tried a search but could not find  the desire result. Can you help me out with a proper solution?